# How to debug MySQL "You have an error in your SQL syntax error"

Tags: mysql, debugging, mysql-error-1064

This is the error

```
Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

This is my query

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO list '. 
   '(bond_amount,bond,prize,prize_amount,draw,draw_date,held_at) '.
   'VALUES ( "bonds", "bonds", prize, p_amount, draw, d_date, held,)';
```

Comment: Also consider that you can use native sql functions if you need the current date to be automatically filled in. Just insert a null value to this field (for example "updated" i/o using the "current_date" keyword). For mysql, you just have to declare a timestamp field with "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" as defaut value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use `current_date` as column name. It is a reserve words of mysql.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: how to debug it tho

Answer (score 5):

`current_date` is a reserved word in mysql.  You should avoid it, but if you *really* want to use it, you must quote it (in back-quotes).

Answer (score 3):

try

```
INSERT INTO staff_service (customer_id,workorder_no,service_date,`current_date`) 
VALUES (2,021,'3112-21-1',CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to use current_date as column name then put current_date between ``(back quotes)